Minimum squares with two different means?
$X∈U(0,θ)$ and $ ∈  ( 0 , 4 )$ . $$  and $$ are independent. We want to estimate   using the Least Squares Method and we obtain the outcomes $ = 5.2$ and $ = 28.3$. Determine the Least Squares estimate of $$  based on these data.
In the solution they are doing: $Q = (x - E(X))^2 + (y - E(Y))^2 =  (x - \frac{\theta}{2})^2 + (y - 2\theta)^2$
This is the formula that I know: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2$
How come they are using this : $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + (y_i - \bar{y})^2$

Your $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ is designed to apply when the $X_i$ have the same expectation; even better would be to say you are seeking the value which minimises $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - m)^2$ and this happens when $\hat m = \bar x$.    But in this question, $X$ and $Y$ do not have the same expectation, so you need a more general approach.

This formula you know $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2$ is fine to find $\bar{x}$. But the task is to get $\theta$ which is obviously determined by both, $X$ and $Y$. Also your ansatz $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2+(y_i-\bar{y})^2$ will only get $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ with no correlation. That is why I suggest to minimise
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\frac{\theta}{2})^2+(y_i-2\theta)^2$$ what equals
$$\frac{4\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ x_i^2\right)+4\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ y_i^2\right) -4\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ x_{i}\right)-16\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ y_i\right)+17n\theta^2}{4}$$
This derived to $\theta$ results
$$\frac{-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ x_i\right)-8\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ y_i\right)+17n\theta}{2}$$
Set to $0$ and solved for $\theta$
$$\theta=\frac{2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ x_{i}+4\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ y_{i}\right)\right)}{17n}$$

In general given a set of data $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ s.t. $X_i\sim p_i(x|\theta)$ the Least Squares esitmator of $\theta$ is the value $\hat{\theta}$ that minimizes $||X-\mathbb{E}_\theta [X]||^2_2$.
In your case the set of data is $(X,Y)$, so you want to minimize $||(X,Y)-\mathbb{E}_\theta [(X,Y)]||^2_2=||(X-\mathbb{E}_\theta [X],Y-\mathbb{E}_\theta [Y])||^2_2=(X-\mathbb{E}_\theta [X])^2+(Y-\mathbb{E}_\theta [Y])^2$
If you are comfortable with vectorial notation that should be clear.
